# Making TextFields remember their content when switching between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, uitextfield

I am writing an app that has a form spread across multiple ViewControllers and a main menu with the submit button on it that opens an e-Mail with the text fields data displayed in it, the only problem i have is that the text boxes don't 'remember' what's been written in them when switching between sections of the form. I have had a look through threads regarding persistent data but have found nothing. I want my application to remember what's been entered in the text fields when switching between views so it can populate the e-Mail with the data but then 'forget' the data again when the user minimises the app. Any advice or pieces of code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Update your question with details about what you are doing so far.

Answer (score 0):

So create a data model singleton and have your view controllers read/write their values from properties of that singleton.

(In viewWillAppear, fetch a pointer to the model singleton and install values from properties of the singleton into your VC's fields. When the user changes a value in a field, have your VC modify the corresponding property of the singleton.

You can write your singleton to listen for the "will enter background" notification and archive it's settings to disk, and make it's init method try to read saved values from disk (or set the values to a defined starting state if they have never been set). You can use NSUserDefaults, NSCoding, or a variety of other approaches for archiving your data.

Comment: No, do not use a singleton for this. That's a bad idea. What if the app allows a user to work on more than one form at a time? Singletons are suggested way too often.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options to persist data. I currently favoring [Realm](https://realm.io), but previously I've used [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html), [YapDatabase](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase), and even simply [serializing objects to disk](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data). Note that if this is your first foray into saving data on iOS, I strongly advise AVOIDING Core Data, as it is very complex and Feature Rich (also, difficult to use correctly until you know it fluently). I recommend you start with serializing objects yourself, then either Realm or YapDatabase.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a singleton `NSObject` class and keep data in that class ... As singleton objects hold data until the application is terminated.

Comment: No, do not use a singleton for this. That's a bad idea.

Comment: @rmaddy Why do you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: Because it's very limiting. It will only allow you to track a single form, it makes testing very difficult, and it is simply a bad design choice. FYI - not my down vote.